# ¿Porque aparece este error sql server?

Tags: c#, sql-server

AL tratar de usar un metodo para insertar en una tabla:

```
    public int AddPersona(Persona p)
    {
        int res;

        using (SqlConnection conexion = new SqlConnection(Conexion.Conectar()))
        {
            conexion.Open();

            using (SqlCommand comando = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Persona(Nombres, Apellidos) VALUES(@Nombres, @Apellidos)", conexion))
            {
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Nombres", p.Nombres);
                comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Apellidos", p.Apellidos);
                res = comando.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }

        return res; 
    }
```

Me aparece este error:

> Se produjo una excepción de tipo 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' en System.Data.dll pero no se controló en el código del usuario
>
> Información adicional: La consulta con parámetros '(@Nombres nvarchar(4000),@Apellidos nvarchar(4000))INSERT INTO P' espera el parámetro '@Nombres', que no se ha proporcionado.

Comment: intenta meterlos de la siguiente manera: ` command.Parameters.Add("@Nombres", SqlDbType.VarChar);
        command.Parameters["@Nombres"].Value = p.Nombres;`

Comment: el codigo que nos muestras esta correcto, intenta realizar un rebuild de la solucion y poner un breakpoint en el codigo para inspeccionar el objeto comando y ver si tienes esos parametros. Tambien quita el using en a definicion del Sqlcommand al estar dentro del using del SqlConnection ya defines un scope que delimita esas variables

Comment: Apoyo la sugerencia de @BlackHole de cambiar el código para no utilizar AddWithValue https://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 0):

Cambia el código de insertar los parámetros a la siguiente forma:

```
comando.Parameters.Add("@Nombres", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 300).Value = p.Nombres;
comando.Parameters.Add("@Apellidos", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 4000).Value = p.Apellidos;
```